# Is it possible to estimate correlation between two dependent variables from two linear regressions?

Tags: regression

I would like to calculate correlation between two regressors in two separate linear regression models, say from

$$y=a_0+a_1x_1+e_1$$ and $$y=b_0+b_1x_2+e_2$$

for $corr(x_1,x_2)$.

Naively, I have \begin{align}
Cov(y,y) & =Cov(a_0+a_1x_1+e_1,b_0+b_1x_2+e_2) \\
 & = Cov(a_1x_1,b_1x_2) \\
 & = a_1b_1 Cov(x_1,x_2)
\end{align}
therefore $$corr(x_1,x_2) = Var(y)(a_1b_1\sigma_1\sigma_2)^{-1}$$ where $\sigma_i^2=Var(x_i)$ for $i=1,2$.

I feel like something has gone missing; has anybody come across this before?

The reason for this is that we don't have individual level data but the regression coefficients themsleves from participating studies in a meta-analysis. We could either request $Var(y)$ or in the case of rank-based inverse normal transformation it takes value of 1. The variances of $x$'s can also be approximated.

Many thanks for your inputs,

Jing Hua

Comment: In these models, the $x_i$ are not random variables.  Please explain, then, what you mean by their correlation.  What data do you have?  What assumptions do you make? Are these formulas for *models* or for *regression estimates?*

Comment: Why not just calculate the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ directly?  Why are you getting $y$ involved at all?

Comment: It is a good reminder that the $x$'s are not random variables. In analysis of genetic data the $x$'s are associated with measurements at different chromosomal positions. The $y$ is just a particular trait such as height. $Corr(x_1,x_2)$ is of interest and is typically obtained from some reference data but often as poor surrogate for the sample in consideration.

Comment: @jbowman: it is straightforward to request some specific pairs but usually each participating study could have tens of millions of $x$'s and it is time-consuming to calculate, store and collect them centrally.. Due to data protection, studies do not share individual level data.

Comment: This appears to be $$\left(\frac{b_1}{a_1}\right)\sqrt{\frac{n_2Var(x_2)}{n_1Var(x_1)}}$$